# How can I have a split column inside a box?

Tags: python, scripting, panel

I'm trying to create a split column inside a box. Seems pretty simple but I just can't figure it out...any ideas?

For example, I would all of the below in a layout.box()

[image]

Comment: Could you add more information about your final goal and how you intend to reach it?

Comment: Well it seems pretty obvious to me but I'll add a little bit more if you wish

Comment: Yes, just like that. My script has a  `box = layout.box()` but it doesn't work with the aligned split columns in my script, I'm trying to change it now to see if it works...

Comment: The thing is I have multiple boxes, how would I go about doing this for just one box? Using the `layout = layout.box()` does it for the whole thing...

Comment: This eg puts Column 2 in a box too http://www.pasteall.org/72269/python

Comment: Yes it's working now, thanks for that. One more thing, can I hide the first box? It doesn't look good having that extra box surrounding everything.

Comment: Ahh, cool, for some reason I thought that had to be in...Thanks for your help, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

you can stack layouts, as each of the container layout elements can host other containers:

```
    layout = self.layout
    box = layout.box()

    # put a column layout into the box
    col = box.column(align = True)

    # also separators work
    col.separator()

    # add a row layout into the column, which is inside the box, which is inside a panel,.....
    row = col.row(align = True)
    row.operator(**example**)
    row.operator(**example**)
```

Comment: Thats good, but they are aligning horizontally, I want them to align vertically, like the above image in 'Column Two'.