# How do I use multiple columns in my add-on UI?

Tags: scripting, add-on

In the add-ons I am writing, I can only put one entity per line. I would like to be able to put multiple of them in one row. Is there something that allows me to do this?

The image from ArchiMesh is what I am aiming for:

[image]

Comment: You can use the `layout.row()` then populate that row with your operators. See : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58368/86891 and you should look into the `ui_panel.py` script template available directly in the text editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create multiple entities in a row, you need to use `layout.row()`. 
What `layout.row()` does is it essentialy tells Blender that you are focusing on a single row. Every prop, operator, etc you put after `layout.row()` will be in that row until you put another `layout.row()`, telling Blender to focus on the next row.

Here is an example:

```
layout = self.layout()
row = layout.row()   # Focus on this row
row.prop(prop, "property")   # Add a property
row.operator("operator")   # Adds an operator in the same row as the property.

row = layout.row()   # A new row
```

and properties here will be on a separate row.
You can also do 
`row = layout.row(align = True)` 
to make the borders of entities flush with each other.

Answer (score 7):

**[`UILayout.column_flow`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.column_flow)**

Perhaps the easiest way to have a 2 column layout  is using the [`column_flow`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.column_flow) layout,  set to 2 columns.

Replacement draw method for *`Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Panel Simple`*

[image]
*11 add cube operator buttons by way of example*

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    cf = layout.column_flow(columns=2, align=False)
    for i in range(11):
        cf.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add")
```

Changing to 3 columns.

[image]
*`cf = layout.column_flow(columns=3)`*

[image]
*`cf = layout.column_flow(columns=3, align=True)`*

Comment: @brockmann sigh, would like to know how the F HNQ's are chosen https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237752/blender-python-column-align  ... very rare to see a python question get in.